# CSS vertical-align slightly off

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

OK, so this is driving me nuts: http://jsfiddle.net/C3YMJ/2/
The images is supposed to be vertically centered in the `div`, but as you can see, it's slightly off-center. I can't get it to center exactly. Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: You should take JSW189's answer, it's the only not forced solution...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the CSS `position` attribute to vertically center your image:

```
div { 
    position:relative;
}

img {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    margin:auto;
}
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/C3YMJ/22/
​

Comment: +1 This is indeed the best solution. Correctly centered and works regardless of height of parent.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the `vertical-align` property, it has no effect as the image has no child elements that it could apply to.

Use `line-height: 20px;` on the `div`.

Comment: I am looking at this. Hold on a second.

Comment: A disadvantage of this is that if the `height` of the div changes, you must also change your `line-height`.

Answer (score 1):

Adding **`line-height: 100%`** to your DIV will solve the problem.

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/C3YMJ/9/

Answer (score 0):

I would take the height off the div and use padding on the top and bottom instead.

```
html: <div><img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" height="10" /></div>​
css:  div {background-color: blue; padding: 5px 0;}
```

That will make it align in the middle.

Answer (score -1):

Your code doesn't work. If you increase both heights it is totally not centered: http://jsfiddle.net/WouterJ/C3YMJ/3/

See the [Centering in the unkown](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/) article from Chris Coyier for more information about how to solve this.

EDIT: Remove wrong statement.

Comment: vertical-align is NOT only for tables.

Comment: @Rob sorry I thought it was. I have removed it from the answer, thank you.